# Freezing while loading image from my S3 bucket and while scrolling tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimage

i've been working on an app that loads a lot of images. I have a table view cell that each of them has an image.
Images are stored in S3 bucket.
Each image is pretty big, around 720 KB, and each time i scroll the screen freezes a bit to get the whole image.

Here's my code that gets image

```
let url: String = "\(K.baseURLForImage)\(cellImageURL)"
let validURL = URL(string: url)
if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: validURL!) {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    cell.cellImage.image = image
}
```

Certainly it is not nice, so is there any way I can get around with this?
I've heard that not using `dequeueReusableCell` is not good

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
I added these lines

```
    if let validURL = URL(string: url) {
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: validURL)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                // error handling
                print("failed URL: '\(url)'")
            }, receiveValue: { (data, response) in
                image = UIImage(data: data)
            })
        return image
    } else {
        return nil
    }
```

But I got `nil` every time I call this function.
I checked that the URL of image is valid.

Comment: `Data(contentsOf:)` is blocking you should use URLSession instead, which will allow you to cancel requests when the cells go off of the screen couple it with a cache it should make it fast. For ease you may wish to use something like SDWebImage or Kingfisher which will manage all of that for you.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. Could you post it as an answer with more precise direction?

Comment: You are returning the image before the recieveValue block is called. Task is still in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with Kingfisher!

Here's my code

```
import Kingfisher

let url: String = "some url"
let validURL = URL(string: url)
KF.url(validURL!)
    .set(to: cell.cellImage)

return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, `Data(contentsOf:)` is a blocking call and any activity on the thread on which this is called will be stopped, including if this is called from the main thread.

Switch to using one of the `URLSession` functions.

One possible example:

```
import Combine

let url = "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
var task: AnyCancellable? // Do not let this go out of scope until data is loaded

if let validURL = URL(string: url) {
    task = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: validURL)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            // error handling
        }, receiveValue: { (data, response) in
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            cell.cellImage.image = image
        })
}
```

Comment: I got `Cannot find type 'AnyCancellable' in scope.` Could you explain why?

Comment: Add `import Combine`

Comment: I added some more. Could you see my question again?